# How can I change the size of a marker in react native maps?

Tags: react-native, maps, android-mapview

I'm trying to reduce the size of the marker on my map, as it is too big.

The problem is that using style = {} does not seem to work in this case.

What am I missing here?

```
   <MapView.Marker
        coordinate={{ latitude: 52.78825, longitude: 13.4324 }}
        title="This should be me"
        description="Some description"
        image={require('../assets/icon.png')}
        style={{width: 26, height: 28}}
      >
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you can render the marker in this manner as per documentation [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md):

```
<Marker ...>
  <Image
    source={require('../assets/icon.png')}
    style={{width: 26, height: 28}}
    resizeMode="contain"
  />
</Marker>
```

Comment: I've tried this approach and it does not show the image at all, but just the default marker. This is why I ended up using the code above.

Comment: @YahirCasas can you try my updated answer? this works on my end.

Comment: it did not work :( Image looks as big as always. THe only thing that changed is that I got a warning now saying "Unable to actiavte KeepAwake".

Comment: It works for me, however in order to preserve the correct coordinates I had to pass `resizeMode="center"` and `resizeMethod="resize"` to the `Image` component.

Comment: This sort of works for me, but I can't change the marker size dynamically at runtime. When I set it to be larger than the initial size (e.g. first 32x32, then 64x64) the marker is cut off at the bottom and right.

Comment: @caike Your solution did work for me thank you very much !